# Firing javascript event cross-browser when text is dragged in to a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm wanting to fire a JavaScript event when the text inside a textbox changes, be it via the user typing text, copy-pasting text or dragging text. The one I'm having trouble with is where users drag text from somewhere in to a textbox.

In the case of dragging text between textboxes, in chrome, the `change()` event is fired once for the textbox that it was dragged from, and a second time when the text is dropped into the destination textbox.

In Firefox or IE8, the change event never fires.

Is there a more suitable event I can listen for that works cross browser?

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ajbeaven/Q8aZp/)

For documentation purposes, here's the code I'm using, copied from the jsfiddle above.

**HTML**

```
<input value="drag me over there">
<input>

<div class="message"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input').change(function() {
    $('.message').append('changed<br/>');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example below works in all recent browsers including ie9, the second one is for ie8 and below.

```
$("some input element").bind("input", function () {
    // do something
});

$('some input element').bind("propertychange", function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.propertyName == "value") {
        // do something
    }
});
```

these will fire the event for however the content inside the input box changes.